# Get user email on Xero after establishing connection

Tags: xero-api

I have managed to connect my user to their xero profile on my application.

However, I am not able to get my user's email from their xero token.
I am using nodejs, what is the method that I can use to get my user's email and number?

I would be using this information for the sign up with xero functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The token Xero return includes an `IdToken` property which is JWT, the `IdToken`'s payload includes the user information like email, firs tname and last name